# How to subclass QWebView?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, subclass, qwebview

In my project I have to subclass QWebView to allow for pop-ups. The thing is, I have absolutely no clue how to subclass QWebView. I tried creating a new header file like this:

```
#ifndef WEB_H
#define WEB_H

#include <QWebView>

class web : public QWebView
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QWebView *web::createWindow(QWebPage::WebWindowType type)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(type);

        QWebView *webView = new QWebView;
        QWebPage *newWeb = new QWebPage(webView);
        webView->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
        webView->setPage(newWeb);
        webView->show();

        return webView;
    }

public:
    explicit web(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // WEB_H
```

However my WebView won't open any pop-ups.

What is the easiest way to subclass QWebView to allow for the createWindow function?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Did you [set the JavaScriptCanOpenWindows attribute of QWebSettings to true](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qwebview.html#createWindow)?

Comment: Yes I did. I also enabled javascript

Comment: Except for the superfluous "web::" prefix, your code should reimplement createWindow() just fine. If it does the right thing I do not know. What let's you think that this is the way to go? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615954/qwebview-allow-pop-ups looks like the better approach.

Comment: Because it doesnt work

Comment: Notice how that post you linked is mine.

Comment: Here is how I do it (yes, with QtWebEngine, but the principle is the same): https://bitbucket.org/xiannox/quill/src/beee664d3b820ec0aea74088a4cf65242b9785ec/widgets/webview.cpp?at=master